# How do I find the values greater than or equal to a and then find the minimum of these greatest values in R?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, if-statement, minimum

```
a <- 0.6875
estFj <- c(-0.8231686, 0.1237904, 1.1967068, 1.3772572)

#What I tried so far is: 

for(i in estFj) {
  if (i >= a) { 
    t = c(i)
  }
}

t
```

But it only gives the value of 1.3772572 whereas I need all the values of `estFj` greater than or equal to a and then find the minimum of these values that are greater than or equal to a!

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 5):

We can use vectorised functions, find the values of `estFj` greater than `a` and then the minimum value of those.

```
> estFj => a # returns a logical vector
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

```
estFj[estFj => a]
[1] 1.196707 1.377257 # uses the logical vector to subset the original vector
```

```
> min(estFj[estFj >= a]) # take the minimum of this
[1] 1.196707
```

Comment: Since edits need to be of a certain length (i think?), please add the "equal to" to the function. It should read `min(estFj[estFj>=a])` and it should be "greater than" not "less than", the symbol doesn't match the text.